# Understanding " ! " Bang Operator in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I declared a callback method inside a Stateful class like:

```
final void Function(int index)? onSelected;
MyBottomNavigationBar({@required this.onSelected});
```

and called using **widget.onselected** inside state class like:

```
widget.onSelected!(_selectedIndex);
```

But I'am not able to understand the actual use of **!** Bang operator. I can't initialize widget.onSelected in constructor without giving **?** during declaration.

My main question is "How **!** bang operator is handling the null values? What's the use of it ?

Comment: [Null-safety needs to use the new `required` keyword, not the old `@required` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67642000/).  Using that will remove the need for `onSelected` to be nullable.  The `!` null-assertions operator simply performs a runtime assertion that the object is not null; if it turns out to actually be null, it will throw an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `Bang` operator does nothing more than tell `Dart` that even if we have defined some variable as a `Nullable` type, it will `definitely` not be null.

Dart's `Nullable safety` and `Flow Analysis` are here to make the developer's life easy by avoiding runtime error and catching them at compile-time itself.

When you define,

```
final void Function(int index)? onSelected;
```

You are telling dart that this variable `may or may not` be assigned a value and thus it may or may not be `null`.

Now, whenever you try to use it like this,

```
widget.onSelected()
```

Dart will warn you that, this is a `Nullable` typed variable hence take extra care.

If Dart didn't tell you this before hand, then you would've realized it after you ran the app and it crashed while trying to call the function.

Now, since Dart has warned you that you cannot use it like that, there are two ways to approach it.

1. Put a null check before using it. This way we are avoiding runtime errors.

   ```
    var onSelected = widget.onSelected;
    if (onSelected != null) onSelected(_selectedIndex);
   ```

   This creation of a new local variable is necessary since Dart's flow analysis only works on local variable null checks and not class level variable null checks.

2. Use the `bang` operator,

   ```
    widget.onSelected!(_selectedIndex)
   ```

   Now the issue with this is that, you are just assuring Dart that it will never be null, but if it were actually null, it will still result in a runtime crash.

So, the `Bang` operator is just a way to bypass Dart's `flow analysis` when you have to access a nullable typed variable.

Hope this clears at least a bit of your doubt.

Comment: Great explaination

Answer (score 3):

The bang operator works like an `assert` statement but in production mode too.

Let's say, this is your function.

```dart
final void Function()? foo;
```

You can't call it directly

```
foo(); // Error
```

Here comes a bang operator, which actually says that Dart I take the full responsibility that this function isn't `null`, let me proceed with the call.

```dart
foo!(); // No error
```

This is essentially equal to doing:

```dart
(foo as Function())();
```

**Note:**

You will run into an error if `foo` was `null`. A good approach is to check for nullability using a local variable and proceed to the call.

```dart
final f = foo;
if (f != null) {
  f();
}
```