# A value of type 'List<Symptoms>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Symptoms>' Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
List<Symptoms> data = snapshot.data;
```

A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.

Comment: Hi there. This should help you. Just use the `bang` operator. `snapshot.data!`.  or `List<String>? data = snapshot.data;`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667071/understanding-bang-operator-in-dart/67667214#67667214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that the `snapshot.data` is `nullable`.

Either use the `bang` operator like `snapshot.data!` or
convert your List to a nullable like `List<Symptoms>?`

Comment: You can accept it as an answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null aware operator incase snapshot.data is null

```dart
List<Symptoms> data = snapshot.data ?? [];
```

This assigns an empty list in case the snapshit data is null.