# Flutter Throw or Return and Class Construction

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Hello i started to learn Flutter with AndroidStudio IDE.
While i following a video to learn i change my code like in video.
But there is diffrences and this diffrences getting me errors.

```
import 'package:flutterogrencitakip/models/student.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Student> students = [
    Student.withId(1, "Yusuf", "Erarslan", 95),
    Student.withId(2, "Yusufff", "Erarslassn", 35),
    Student.withId(3, "YusufffAAA", "ErAAAarslassn", 15)
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Öğrenci Takip Sistemi"),
        ),
        body: buildBody());
  }

  Widget buildBody() {
   return Column(
     children:<Widget>[
       Expanded(
         child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: students.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
             return Text(students[index].firstName);
             }),
       )
     ],
   );

  }
}
```

This code getting me error even i have student.dart in models folder.
This is output.

```
lib/main.dart:40:42: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
             return Text(students[index].firstName);
```

is this because of im using return instead of throw or my void main class and class myApp classes are has wrong definition ?
Because it was like that.

```
void main(){
const MyApp bla bla bla i can't remember exactly
}
```

### Screenshots

My Project Folders:

[image: My Project Folders]

My Problems:

[image: My Problems]

Changed area by me:

[image: Changed area by me]

My Student Class:

```
class Student{
  int? id;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  int? grade;
  String? status;

  (String firstName, String lastName, int grade){
    this.firstName= firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
    this.grade  = grade;
  }

  //named constructor
  Student.withId(int id,String firstName, String lastName, int grade){
    this.id=id;
    this.firstName= firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
    this.grade  = grade;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your `Student` class defined? I guess `firstName` is defined to have the type `String?`.

Comment: Can you include `Student` model class?

Comment: I included my Student class and screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Text` widget accepts a parameter type of `String` (not accepting null) and not `String?` (nullable).

One solution to this is to catch if the String you supplied (in this case, the firstname) is null

```
return Text(students[index].firstName ?? '');
```

The above code will output `''` if the `students[index].firstName` is `null`;

Answer (score 1):

On your model class `Student` define with nullable  `String? firstName;`

But a `Text` widget needs a real text, not null. So I will suggest to check null then assign it, or you can provide default value like this:

`Text(students[index].firstName ?? '');`

Check more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

If you are *absolutely sure* that your nullable string in fact *has* a value, you can add `!` at the end:

`Text(students[index].firstName!)`

> The Bang`!` operator does nothing more than telling Dart that even if we have defined some variable as a Nullable type, it will definitely not be null.
> For more about [bang operator question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667214/10157127)

Comment: `Text(students[index].firstName!)` will make the compiler happy and make the user ask their next SO question, why they have this runtime error.

Comment: That's kinda true, that's why I suggested checking null first,

Comment: I know, I didn't downvote it because you did add the better version, it's just that many people don't read that far, they only see that `!` makes their error go away and then they are totally surpised that they have runtime errors :(

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cause the variable `firstName?` is nullable. Meaning that at a certain point it could be `null`, `Text()` only accepts `String` so the program understands that at some point it could get a `null` instead of a `String` then throw the error.

In your model make the variable not nullable and it should work.

`firstName` instead of `firstName?`

Notice that if you make this the variable `firstName` will always need value.

Comment: If i change my variables firstName instead of firstName? , im getting this error
https://www.hizliresim.com/ltwm486

Comment: @demonjoseph Please read about null safety in Dart starting from: https://dart.dev/null-safety