# Null safety problem - map contains non nullable values

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

Why is there an error:

```
A value of type 'TestBloc?' can't be returned from the method 'createFromId' because it has a return type of 'TestBloc.
```

The `map` contains values of type `TestBloc` (not of type `TestBloc?`) so it is impossible to assign a `null` value.

```
class TestBloc {
  String id;
  TestBloc({
    required this.id,
  });
}

class TestBlocFactory {
  final Map<String, TestBloc> _createdElements = HashMap<String, TestBloc>();

  TestBloc createFromId(String id) {
    if (_createdElements.containsKey(id)) {
      return _createdElements[id]; // !! ERROR !!
    } else {
      TestBloc b = TestBloc(id: id);
      _createdElements[id] = b;
      return b;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define you map as `<String, TestBloc>` but still `_createdElements[id]` may return a `null` value, because the `id` key may not available so it may return `null` but because you check it in your if condition you can use `!` (as
@MendelG said) or you can cast it like this:

```
if (_createdElements.containsKey(id)) {
  return _createdElements[id] as TestBloc; // <--- change this
} else {
  TestBloc b = TestBloc(id: id);
  _createdElements[id] = b;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: How will it return `null` if he checks for the key first?

Comment: dart thinks that may be null its not gonna be null because there are checking for the key @MendelG

Comment: not mistake, its the way dart works, using `!`could do the work too. @MendelG

Comment: @PiotrTemp was it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking that the `map` contains the correct `id` with `_createdElements.containsKey`, you know for sure that it won't return `null`. So, it's safe to use the `!` operator which says "I won't be null"

```dart
class TestBloc {
  String id;
  TestBloc({
    required this.id,
  });
}

class TestBlocFactory {
  final Map<String, TestBloc> _createdElements = HashMap<String, TestBloc>();

  TestBloc createFromId(String id) {
    if (_createdElements.containsKey(id)) {
      return _createdElements[id]!;
    } else {
      TestBloc b = TestBloc(id: id);
      _createdElements[id] = b;
      return b;
    }
  }
}
```

##### See also

- [Understanding " ! " Bang Operator in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667071/understanding-bang-operator-in-dart)
- [Understanding null safety (dart.dev)](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: I know that "!" will do the job, but I didn't understand why is it necessary when types are strictly given. So I looked for definition of [] operator of Map class which is:
```V? operator [](Object? key);```
Operator [] can return null (even when value type is non nullable) if key is null.

Comment: @PiotrTemp I didn't fully understand, are you saying or asking?
are you saying that it isn't safe to use `!` in this example?

Comment: My question was why in Map there are non nullable values, but when we access them thay are nullable. Now I understand. Thanks for disscussion.

Comment: @PiotrTemp Got you. Would you consider marking which ever answer has helped you the most [as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (Click on the checkmark next to the answer)