# nulled error in android studio ontap function

Tags: android, xml, flutter, firebase, function

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:safehandsv2/utils/quotes.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  //const CustomAppBar({super.key});

  Function? onTap;
  int? quoteIndex;
  CustomAppBar({this.onTap, this.quoteIndex});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap:() {
        **onTap!();**
      },
      child: Text(sweetSayings[quoteIndex!],
      
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, ),
      
      ),

      
    );
  }
}
```

so here the error I'm getting is null not defined etc.

```
error - Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `onTap` is defined as *nullable* (the `?`):

```dart
Function? onTap;
```

then, you're calling the function using the `!` operator, which means to say "I won't be null" but when you called it, it was *indeed null*.

So, first, check if it's null before calling it:

```dart
onTap: () {
        if (onTap != null) {
          onTap!();
        }
      },
```

When your calling `CustomAppBar` you're probably not passing in an `onTap`, since it's optional.

##### See also

- [Understanding " ! " Bang Operator in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667071/understanding-bang-operator-in-dart)
- [Understanding null safety (dart.dev)](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)